# How do I pass args from command line to rake then rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake, rspec2, rakefile

I'm trying to pass a couple of variables through the command line to rake to be used in rspec.

From what i gather i can do this to pass args into my rake task:

```
task :my_task, :arg1, :arg2 do |t, args|
  puts "Args were: #{args}"
end
```

but I'm using rspec so my rake task looks like this:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:my_task), :arg1, :arg2 do |t, args|
 puts args.arg1
 puts args.arg2
end
```

which doesn't work.

also I havent figured out how to pass it to my rspec spec file

Comment: I don't know rspec, but your code example looks like it has a little typo. The brackets in RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new should include the arguments: RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:my_task, :arg1, :arg2)

Answer (score 0):

How do you call rake?

For your example you have to call:

```
rake mytask[val1,val2]
```

I'm not sure about your 2nd code example.
args should be a hash with keys :arg1 and :arg2.
So you may use

```
puts args[:arg1]
```

I'm in doubt if args.arg1 will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the original question, but I had to solve a similar problem. You don't have to change much of your initial idea:

```
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:my_task, [:arg1, :arg2]) do |t, args|
 puts args.arg1
 puts args.arg2
end
```

Then call it e.g. via:

```
rake my_task["hello","world"]
```